# Error with waiting on image load in jquery

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-404, image-loading

I have a small problem with the following script:

```
$(document).load('img', function(){
     alert('images have loaded');
})
```

The alert will pop up after all images have loaded, which is correct. However, the 'img' generates a 404 warning in the console.

```
GET http://www.website.com/img 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing that wrong, right now you're trying to load data with ajax from the URL `img`, as that's what the `load()` method does, and that's why you're getting the 404.

Using a delegated event handler like that makes no sense, if you're trying to wait for all external resources (as in images etc.) to load, use `window.onload`

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
     alert('images have loaded');
});
```

Comment: DOH! Yep, I guess that makes more sense. It was late when I wrote that :)